# implementing the comparable interface for the type File to sort by length of the filename

Tags: comparable

I would like to define a new class FileSorter that extends the type File and implements the comparable interface by defining a compareTo() to sort by the length of the filename.

```
public class FileSorter extends File implements Comparable<File>
{
    private int size;

    public FileSorter(String pathname) 
    {
        super(pathname);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public int compareTo(File b)
    {
        if (this.length() == b.length())
            return 0;
        else if (this.length() > b.length())
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
}



public class FileSorterDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FileSorter directory = new FileSorter(args[0]);
        FileSorter[] files = ((FileSorter) directory).listFiles();

        Arrays.sort(files);

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
            System.out.println(files[i].getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the following working solution using comparator. Is this acceptable?
Can this be implemented using Comparable Interface?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
public class FileSortByFilenameLength implements Comparator<File>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(File arg0, File arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (arg0.getName().length() > arg1.getName().length())
            return 1;
        else if (arg0.getName().length() < arg1.getName().length())
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}



public class FileSorterDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File directory = new File(args[0]);
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();

        Arrays.sort(files, new FileSortByFilenameLength());

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        System.out.println(files[i].getName() + " - " + files[i].getName().length());
    }
}
```